# Getting one value from a return() statement when I execute sapply, and another value when I execute the statement manually

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

SO users - I'm working on some code for a movie recommendation algorithm exercise.  I've written an sapply statement to evaluate the best penalty (lambda), in order to reduce the weight of small groups of ratings.  I'm expecting an output of RMSE values between .8 and 1, but I'm getting values over 1000 from my sapply statement.  When I manually execute just the RMSE function, I get output that matches my expectations.  Why am I getting such drastically different results from the sapply statement versus manually executing the same RMSE function?

```
# Load packages
if(!require(tidyverse)) install.packages("tidyverse", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
if(!require(caret)) install.packages("caret", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
if(!require(data.table)) install.packages("data.table", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

# Determine the average rating across all movies, from all users  
mu <- mean(edx_train$rating)

# Generate a sequence of lambdas for tuning, to determine what penalty value produces the least RMSE with training data
lambdas <- seq(0, 10, 0.25)

# Test various values of lambda
rmses <- sapply(lambdas, function(l){
  # Determine how each movie's average rating deviates from the average for all movies (movie effect)
  b_i <- edx_train %>% 
    group_by(movieId) %>%
    summarize(b_i = sum(rating - mu)/(n()+l))
  # Join the movie effect data back to the training data and determine user effect
  b_u <- edx_train %>% 
    left_join(b_i, by="movieId") %>%
    group_by(userId) %>%
    summarize(b_u = sum(rating - b_i - mu/(n()+l)))
  # Join movie effect and user effect data to the partitioned test data (from the training data set)
  predicted_ratings <- 
    edx_test %>% 
    left_join(b_i, by = "movieId") %>%
    left_join(b_u, by = "userId") %>%
    mutate(pred = mu + b_i + b_u) %>%
    .$pred

  # Identify any N/A values resulting from cases in the test data where there is no corresponding training data 
  # from which to base a prediction
  na_index <- which(is.na(predicted_ratings))
  # Create data set for predicted ratings of test data, removing any N/A values
  predicted_ratings <- predicted_ratings[-na_index]
  # Remove any test records that correspond with the predictions identified as having N/A values
  edx_test <- edx_test[-na_index]

  # Evaluate RMSE of remaining predictions and corresponding actual ratings from the test data
  return(RMSE(edx_test$rating, predicted_ratings))
})
```

A sample of the edx_test and edx_train data sets:

```
edx_test_ex <- structure(
    list(userId = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L),
         movieId = c(7155, 8783, 27821, 39, 153, 344),
         rating = c(3.5, 5, 4.5, 3, 5, 2),
         timestamp = c(1164885564L, 1136075857L, 1136418616L, 844417037L,844416699L, 844416699L),
         title = c("Calendar Girls (2003)",
                   "Village, The (2004)",
                   "Interpreter, The (2005)",
                   "Clueless (1995)",
                   "Batman Forever (1995)",
                   "Ace Ventura: Pet Detective (1994)"),
         genres = c("Comedy",
                    "Drama|Mystery|Thriller",
                    "Drama|Thriller", 
                    "Comedy|Romance",
                    "Action|Adventure|Comedy|Crime",
                    "Comedy")),
    row.names = c(NA, -6L),
    class = "data.frame"
)

edx_train_ex <- structure(
    list(userId = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
         movieId = c(377, 520, 539, 588, 589, 594),
         rating = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
         timestamp = c(838983834L, 838984679L, 838984068L, 838983339L, 838983778L, 838984679L), 
         title = c("Speed (1994)",
                   "Robin Hood: Men in Tights (1993)",
                   "Sleepless in Seattle (1993)",
                   "Aladdin (1992)",
                   "Terminator 2: Judgment Day (1991)",
                   "Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs (1937)"),
         genres = c("Action|Romance|Thriller",
                    "Comedy",
                    "Comedy|Drama|Romance",
                    "Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Musical",
                    "Action|Sci-Fi",
                    "Animation|Children|Drama|Fantasy|Musical")),
    row.names = c(NA, -6L),
    class = "data.frame"
)
```

I'm getting a series of error messages: "In true_ratings - predicted_ratings :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" but I've confirmed that the true rating and predicted rating outputs are the same length.  And as I mentioned, the RMSE function is working correctly when I highlight and run just the line 
    `RMSE(edx_test$rating, predicted_ratings)`

This is my first post, sorry if I'm giving too much information, not enough information, or otherwise being obtuse.

amber

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Right now we don't have copies of `edx_train` or `edx_test`, so we can't reproduce the issue that you are facing here. Could you please update your code to include small examples of these two data frames, so that we can run your code and get the same error that you're getting? Thanks!

Comment: `dput()` will output the contents of a variable for this purpose

Comment: Sorry, that makes sense - thanks for the `dput()` suggestion.

Comment: @amber You should add the libraries that you are using to your example. This code relies on the `tidyverse` in order to run correctly, but you don't have that in your code. I edited your post to add that this is a `tidyverse` question as you'll get better help that way.

Comment: Oh, right on - thanks, @TARehman!

Comment: for better chance at assistance, you need to further isolate your problem. I tried running your code, but didn't have mu, didn't have the package RMSE came from, data is named something else. Try copying your code into a new file and session.

Comment: then, as you said, if RMSE(edx_test$rating, predicted_ratings) ran, what mu and l (lambda) did it run with?

Comment: you also should test all the code inside the function, before using sapply and function. but I'm confused - you said RMSE(edx_test$rating, predicted_ratings) did run, so you must have generated edx_test and predicted_ratings already previously??

Comment: Hi, @ArthurYip - thanks for taking a look at this with me; sorry for leaving out those details.  I edited my code to reflect the packages used, and also to add the line where mu is generated.

Comment: (Continued from previous comment)  I have run each section of the code within sapply as part of my troubleshooting process, so you're correct that I've generated all of the variables and data sets outside of sapply.  When I ran each bit of sapply individually, I replaced `l` with 10 (the max value from `lambdas`).